# Uanable to create MediaPlayer

Tags: android, media-player

I have been using a mp3 file in my application for over 3 weeks and it was working fine.

Now it shows in logcat as unable to create media player

I have to comment out //mp.start(); to make my application work.

Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android VMs are rather finicky, you may want to first try creating a new VM, and starting before you try launching the application.  If it works set the new VM as the default.

You will also want to put mp.start() in a try catch block and logd any exceptions.  This will also let you display a message to the user on failures without crashing on a published version.

Answer (score 0):

Have you started testing in a newer version of emulator. I had a similar issue with bitmap. It was working fine until I tested in Android 2.3 emulator. It took a while for me to figure out it is the new emulator that was bottleneck.

Try testing in proven emulator versions. If it works there, you can then figure out what needs to be changed to make it work in new versions.

Are you playing a number of mp3 files. If yes, you might want to call mp.release in your onCompletion Listener
sample code..

```
// wherever media is playing
mMedia.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);

private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener mCompletionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        mp.release();
        finish();
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't see in the question or the subject that the user states they are using an emulator... Why is this the assumption then?  I say this because I am using a Galaxy S3 (real) device and seeing this exact same problem.

Comment: Motorola Milestone (2.2), same here. Oddly enough, with my AOC Tablet (2.3), works fine.